# Problema al invocar servicios web de manera dinámica en JAVA

Tags: java, webservice, glassfish

Tengo un problema con un proyecto que estoy implementando. el proyecto crea el código fuente para clientes de servicios web (a través del wsimport de java) de manera dinámica y los invoca a través de este código y con el uso de reflexión. Esto esta bajo glassfish 4.1.1

cuando hay un solo servicio web a ejecutar no hay problema, pero cuando es más de un servicio web a veces (no siempre) ocurren errores en el servidor del tipo **IllegalStateException: ESTE CONTENEDOR WEB NO SE HA INICIALIZADO**.

El error arrojado es:

> javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started

he consultado sobre este error (`IllegalStateException`) y la solución que plantean es editar el archivo de configuración de `domain.xml` pero no me ha funcionado.

Tengo la sensación de que puede haber conflictos cuando se crea el código para los clientes de los servicios, este código se genera en tiempo de ejecución y puedo ver en los log que el servidor detecta este nuevo código e intenta analizarlo pero a vaces no alcanza a hacerlo antes de que mi implementación lo intente utilizar.

El caso es que solo ocurre a veces y pasa cuando intento llamar a más de un servicio web.

para cada servicio web que se va a generar se crea un hilo donde se ejecuta

```
@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wsimport -keep -s "+dirJava+" -d "+dirClass+" "+dirWSDLServiceWeb);
        File dirServicios=new File(dirJava+"\\"+namePackage);          
        while(!readySRC){
            sleep(200);
            if(dirServicios.exists() && dirServicios.listFiles().length > 0){
                // Esperar a crear los .class 
                sleep(3000);
                readySRC=true;
            }               
            CONTADOR_INTENTOS_CREACION++;
            if(CONTADOR_INTENTOS_CREACION >= 15) break;
        }            
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        readySRC=false;
        System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION : "+ex.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {  
        readySRC=false;
        System.out.println("InterruptedException : "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Luego en el hilo principal se valida si el atributo `readySRC` es verdadero, entonces se intenta acceder al código generado a través de reflexión.
pero cuando hay más de un servicio por crear me arroja problemas.

alguien puede ayudarme?

Gracias.

Comment: Luis, sería buena idea agregaras tu código.

Comment: Hola, es que es bastante grande, voy a editar la pregunta con un poco del codigo